# Find the Fixed points (Knaster-Tarski Theorem)

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, fixed-point-theorems

Let $L=\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ be a complete lattice of subsets of $\mathbb N$.

a) Justify that the function $F(X)=\mathbb N \setminus X$ does not have a Fixed Point.

I don't know how to solve this.

b) Be $F(X)=\left\{ x+1 \mid x\in X \right\} $. Find the smallest and the greatest Fixed points. (You can start with $\emptyset $ and $\mathbb N$ and see where it goes.)

**My Solution**:

Here I started like this for the least fixed point: $\emptyset \sqsubseteq  F(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ (but this is just assumption, how do I prove this ?)

For greatest Fixed Point I have $\mathbb N \sqsupseteq  F(\mathbb N) \sqsupseteq F(F(\mathbb N)) \sqsupseteq \cdots $ (But I can't make a assumption about the greatest fixed point). Which is it and why?

Comment: Can you find any other fixed point, other than $\emptyset$? What would it mean for a non-empty set $X$ to be a fixed point? What do we know about non-empty subsets of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: First question: No i can't find any other except the empty set. second question: It means there is a $x \in X$ so that $F(x)=x$. Third question I am not sure.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews does a greatest fixed point exist ? If it does not exist is it then a $\emptyset$ ?

Comment: If $x\in X$ then $f(x)$ doesn't make sense, because $x$ is a single natural number, and $f$ has subsets of the natural numbers as its domain.

Comment: I put \setminus, \mid, and \cdots in the appropriate places here.  The first two automatically provide proper spacing, whereas the things that were here before do not. If you write A\sqsupseteq B\sqsupseteq... instead of A\sqsupseteq B\sqsupseteq\cdots in standard LaTeX, you'll see $A\sqsupseteq B\sqsupseteq\text{...}$ instead of $A\sqsupseteq B\sqsupseteq\cdots$, and even in MathJax you get something inferior to the latter. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, i wan't to but I don't get it. Lets try first the a), why is there no Fixed Point ?

Comment: Where your question says "a complete lattice of a subset", might you have meant "a complete lattice of subsets"? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes. It is written in German so I translated in English. Yes it is subsets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $\mathbb N\setminus X$ is the complement of $X$.  Its members are precisely those members of $\mathbb N$ that are *not* members of $X$.  A fixed point of the function $X\mapsto N\setminus X$ would be a set that is its own complement.  It would satisfy $X=\mathbb N\setminus X$.  If the number $1$ is a member of $X$ then $1$ would not be a member of $\mathbb N\setminus X$, since the latter set is the complement of $X$, but if $X=\mathbb N\setminus X$, then the number $1$ being a member of $X$ would mean that $1$ *is* a member of $\mathbb N\setminus X$.  A similar contradiction follows from the assumption that $1$ is not a member of $X$.

The empty set is a fixed point of $X\mapsto \{x+1\mid x\in X\}$.  If $X$ is any non-empty set, then $X$ has a smallest member.  The smallest member of $X$ is not a member of $\{x+1\mid x\in X\}$.  Therefore $X$ is not a fixed point of that function. That function therefore has only one fixed point.

Comment: Thanks I now understand the first one.

Comment: @Devid : Suppose $X=\{15,23,97,245,\ldots\}$  Then $\{x+1\mid x\in X\}=\{16,24,98,246,\ldots\}$.  That set cannot be equal to $X$ because $15$ is not a member of that set.  That's the argument in my second paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

To justify that a function $f$ does not have a fixed point you have to argue as follows:

> Suppose that $X$ was a fixed point of $f$, then $f(X)=X$. But now we have that ...

Where the ellipsis denote the rest of the arguments which you should fill for yourself. (Hint: Consider what is $f$ in this context).

---

As for the second part, you are right that $\varnothing$ is a fixed point, and therefore the least fixed point. Simply because $\varnothing\subseteq F(\varnothing)$ on one hand, and on the other hand, what is $\{x+1\mid x\in\varnothing\}$?

What is the largest fixed point? Well, here's a hint:

Note that if $A\subseteq\Bbb N$ is non-empty, then $\min A\notin F(A)$.

Comment: Yeah the least fixed point was easy to find, but the largest fixed point is much harder to understand.

Comment: Read the last line again. What can you infer from it?

Comment: but what is $F(A)$ ? I think I understand, there is no minimum, because we added +1. But how will that help me with largest fixed point. Thanks for the helping.

Comment: $F(A)=\{x+1\mid x\in A\}$. It's not that there's no minimum, it just shows that $A\setminus F(A)\neq\varnothing$. What does that tell you?